# Java strange class cast exception

Tags: java, interface, functional-programming, classcastexception

Could anyone help me understand why in 1 situation I do not have ClassCastException? At least String::trim is not a MagicFunction.

```
public class Main {

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface MagicFunction extends Function<String, String> {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // 1. OK
        final MagicFunction fun1 = String::trim;

        // 2. java.lang.ClassCastException
        Function<String, String> trim = String::trim;
        final MagicFunction fun2 = (MagicFunction) trim;
    }
}
```

Comment: It boils down to the difference between what you write and what's actually compiled. Essentially, with case 2, you've definitively created a `Function<String, String>` (which does not subclass `MagicFunction`) and cannot be casted to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) (like `String::trim`) are a bit weird; unlike most expressions in Java, they don't really have a type of their own. Something like this:

```
System.out.println((String::trim).getClass());
```

won't even compile, because it doesn't give the compiler enough information about what type `String::trim` should be.

Instead, the type of every method reference must be *inferred* from the surrounding context, e.g. by being the right-hand-side of an assignment statement (using the type of the variable on the left-hand-side) or by being passed directly to a method (using the type of the method parameter). The compiler then generates a class for you that implements the appropriate type using the method in question. Something like this:

```
final MagicFunction fun1 = String::trim;
```

is effectively equivalent to this:

```
final MagicFunction fun1 = new MagicFunction() {
    public String apply(final String s) {
        return s.trim();
    }
};
```

Note that this only works for specific types, called "functional interface" types. The [detailed rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8) are a bit complicated, but the basic idea is that it has to be an interface type with exactly one abstract method. The method reference supplies the implementation of that method. (And of course, the signature of this method has to be compatible with the signature of the method reference; you can't use `String::trim` to implement `Function<Integer, Integer>`.)

Comment: Type casts also provide an appropriate context, e.g. it would work if the variable `trim` was initialized like `Function<String, String> trim = (MagicFunction)String::trim;`, which of course only works if the cast is immediately preceding the method reference rather than being only applied to the already constructed object.

Answer (score -2):

"And of course, the signature of this method has to be compatible with the signature of the method reference; you can't use String::trim to implement Function<Integer, Integer>."  -  yes, you can. Here is an example

```
String g = "testString";
testMethod(String::trim, g);


public static <T, R> void testMethod(Function<T, R> func, T t) {
    func.apply(t);
}
```

Comment: Answers on Stack Overflow are meant to answer the question, not debate an accepted answer. See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing a good Stack Overflow answer for more information.